# Define REST endpoint that returns a List

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, api

How can I return a list from a controller class?

My current code:

```
@PostMapping(value = Endpoint.RRESOURCE_customer_ID)
public ResponseEntity<customerDto> getLocationsByLocationIds(@RequestBody @Validated @RequestParam(name = "ids", required = true) List<Long> ids) {
      List<customerDto> customerListDto = customerService.findcustomerIds(ids);
      return ResponseEntity.ok(customerListDto);
}
```

The error I receive:

> ```
> Error:(51, 41) java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
>     equality constraints: com.testclass.cust.common.dto.output.CustomerDto
>     lower bounds: java.util.List<com.customer.common.dto.output.CustomerDto>
> ```

The `findcustomerIds` method:

```
@Transactional
public List<customerDto> findcustomerIds(List<Long> customerIds) {
    List<customer> customerList = repository.findAll(customerIds);
    return mapper.mapAsList(customerList, customerDto.class);
}
```

I am not sure about the next definition.

```
public ResponseEntity<customerDto> getLocationsByLocationIds(@RequestBody @Validated @RequestParam(name ="ids", required = true) List<Long> ids)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your endpoint as follows:

```
@PostMapping(value = Endpoint.RRESOURCE_customer_ID)
public List<CustomerDto> getLocationsByLocationIds(@RequestBody List<Long> ids) {
    return customerService.findcustomerIds(ids);
}
```

Note that you can't have both `@RequestBody` and `@RequestParam` on the same field. The field is **either** the HTTP Requests body or a HTTP Request parameter.

Comment: how can i send request to that method with responsebody ? i just want to send a list of longs for id of customer like ["1","3","15"]

Comment: With `RestTemplate`. You can see examples here https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template

Answer (score 0):

You have to return a List of "customerDto" in your ReponseEntity class

```
@PostMapping(value = Endpoint.RRESOURCE_customer_ID)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<List<customerDto> > getLocationsByLocationIds(@RequestParam List<Long> ids) {
      List<customerDto> customerListDto = customerService.findcustomerIds(ids);
      return ResponseEntity.ok(customerListDto);
}
```